# Top part of Fragment items is hidden under Action bar

Tags: android

I am new to android development and I have one problem now:

*Top part of Fragment items is hidden under Action bar*

I have found several similiar questions here, but haven't solved this problem yet.

This is **fragment_new_visit.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="visible"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".NewVisitFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="117dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

This is **app_bar_main2.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main2" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is **content_main2.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main2">

</LinearLayout>
```